# Options for operating phone remotely

Tags: remote-control, remote-access, screencast

For *Remote Desktop* functionality there is *Droid VNC Server*, other current better options?
*Android Screencast* (Seems like something that was promising)?

I used to "Wi-Fi keyboards", but now with VNC its not so interesting, as I have to set the input-method on the phone.  (i think "Remote Keyboard" app could be interesting if there are situations when VNC are difficult.

What about options for working directly with the phone, like desktop SMS applications?

I am thinking of any way of connecting (Bluetooth, USB, Wi-Fi....) with a rooted phone?

Primarily Windows Desktop (But many possibilities is always better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hae a look at [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) for desktop SMS.

It works as a kind of web server on your phone, which means you have to access it from a secure web page (downside: works only inside the same WiFi network).

But next to smses you can do a lot more with it, but I recommend you have a look at it yourself.

Comment: I am checking it out.  There are many apps that doesnt work over the Internet, but  there should be some VPN solution?

Comment: You could setup [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) in your router if your intention is to let "someone from the outside" access it (or to access a device you left home with *Airdroid* or the like running). Of course, if you've got VPN setup and running, that's obsolete as you can act as if you'd be within the same network already.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Samsung Phone you can check out Teamviewer QuickSupport which lets you fully control your Phone.

There are also ways to use it with other Roms and Phones.

See:
[QuickSupport Mod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1836780)

Comment: How easy is it to set up?

How performant is it compared to VNC
(I love TV, but I have the impression it performes less well than VNC for desktop computers).

Does the Teamviewer VPN also work?